# How to define a subroutine in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, subroutine

In C# a `RemoveAllFilesByExtenstion` subroutine could be, for example, decleard like this:

```
void RemoveAllFilesByExtenstion(string targetFolderPath, string ext)
{
...
}
```

and used like:

```
RemoveAllFilesByExtenstion("C:\Logs\", ".log");
```

How can I defne and call a subroutine with the same signature from a PowerShell script file (ps1)?

Comment: Sorry to nitpick on an old post but just for clarity: The C# Language Reference does not use the term 'subroutine'.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Pretty simple to convert this to PowerShell:

```
function RemoveAllFilesByExtenstion([string]$targetFolderPath, [string]$ext)
{
...
}
```

But the invocation has to use space separated args but doesn't require quotes unless there's a PowerShell special character in the string:

```
RemoveAllFilesByExtenstion C:\Logs\ .log
```

OTOH, if the function is indicative of what you want to do, this can be done in PowerShell easily:

```
Get-ChildItem $targetFolderPath -r -filter $ext | Remove-Item
```

Comment: hint: the **local function** must be put **after the main function declaration** like this: `[CmdletBinding()] param( ... ) ... function myLocalFunction( ... ) { ... } ...`

Answer (score 3):

There are no subroutines in PowerShell, you need a function:

```
function RemoveAllFilesByExtenstion    
{
   param(
     [string]$TargetFolderPath,
     [string]$ext
   )  

    ... code... 
}
```

To invoke it :

```
RemoveAllFilesByExtenstion -TargetFolderPath C:\Logs -Ext *.log
```

If you don't the function to return any value make sure you capture any results returned from the commands inside the function.

Comment: Thanks. The term sub-routine is more "a reusable" "re-callable" piece of code, so the term "function" is a subset of "subroutine" in my opinion.

Comment: In VBscript there is actually a distinction between a subroutine (keyword: sub) and a function (keyword: function). The former returns no value and the latter does. Folks going to PowerShell from VBS might get a little confused that PowerShell only has functions which may ore may not return a value.